# Create database backup, ignore column

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'd like to create a database backup using SSMS.
The backup file will be a .bak file, but I would like to ignore 1 column in a certain table, because this column isn't necessary, but it takes up 95% of the backup size.

The column values should all be replaced by 0x00 (column type is varbinary(max), not null).

What's the best way to do this?

FYI: I know how to generate a regular backup using Tasks => Back Up..

Comment: How are you planning to use this backup? isnt the data for that binary column required when restoring? do you need only this one table in your backup?

Comment: @ughai The database backup I would like to retrieve is a production backup. This backup contains a lot of data, but also a table of attachments. This table has a content column in which the attachment content is stored as  a binary string (which I don't need for my debugging). That's why I'd like to "ignore" this column, but since it's a not-nullable field, it'd have to have value 0x00 in my backup, but the live database cannot be adjusted to do this.

Comment: So you primary concern is that ftp of the database backup would require lots of disk space for data which you don't need and waste time and bandwidth

Comment: @ughai Indeed, we want to improve the speed of the backup transfer by leaving out unnecessary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a long way of doing what you ask. Its basically create a new restored database, remove the non required data and then do a new backup again.

1. Create a Backup of the production database.
2. Restore the backup locally on production with a new name
3. Update the column with `0x00`
4. Shrink the database (Shrink is helpful when doing a restore. This wont reduce the bak file size)
5. Take the backup of the new database (Also use Backup Compression to reduce the size even more)
6. Ftp the bak file

If you only needed a few tables, you could have used `bcp` but that looks out of the picture for your current requirement.

Answer (score 1):

From SQL Server native backups, you can't. You'd have to restore the database to some other location and then migrate usefull data.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a copy of your table without the column and backup using filegroups https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191539(SQL.90).aspx